# Set active class with react-router Link that has an optional URL parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I set the active class name of a Link for a path that contains an optional parameter?

Below are some details of what I am trying to achieve:

- A route in my application has a path that contains an optional URL parameter - eventId:

  `<Route path="/sendInvite(/:eventId)" component={SendInviteContainer} />`
- In my main navigation component there is a `<Link/>` that points to /sendInvite path (without the optional param):

  `<Link to="/sendInvite" activeClassName="active">Send Invite</Link>`

If the user accesses the path `/sendInvite`, the Link has now an active class set, which is the correct behavior for this case.

**However**, when the user accesses `/sendInvite/15` , the Link in my navigation that points to /sendInvite has no active class set.

Any ideas on how to set the Link to active with the optional parameter in the address bar?

Comment: In [DOCS](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link)
 it says that `Link` should be active even is URL points to the descendant of the linked route

_A `<Link>` can know when the route it links to is active and automatically apply an `activeClassName` and/or `activeStyle` when given either prop. The `<Link>` will be active if the current route is either the linked route or any descendant of the linked route._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put you `/sendInvite(/:eventId)` under `/sendInvite` route

It should be something like this:-

```
<Route path="/sendInvite" component={container} >
     <Route path="/sendInvite(/:eventId)" component={SendInviteContainer} />
</Route>
```

This should keep you parent route active.

You can check out [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/active-links/app.js), check for how users part is taken care off in router, it would solve your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Another *and better option in my opinion* would be `isActive`, example:

```
<NavLink
    to='path'
    className='whatever'
    isActive={() => window.location.hash.indexOf('sendInvite') > -1}>
    Title
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {NavLink, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
<NavLink 
 ctiveClassName="activeLink" className="month"
 to="/tab1/"
 onClick={() => /*to scroll to top*/
  window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:"smooth"})
 }
>
Tab 1
</NavLink>
```

**in css**

```
.activeLink{
 background-color:#f00; /*for red background*/
}
```